# Local variable referenced before assignment. Global Variable not read inside function. [Python 3.7]

Tags: python, string, function, global, local

I have two global variables being declared just outside a function. When I try to access their values just inside the function, one of them gets identified while the other fails to get accessed. [Python 3.7.6 on linux]

```
px_var_name = "Particles_Px_subset_fract_electron"
xPx_title = "Px vs. x"

def proc_single_file(file_nam):
    print("starting file processing:" + file_nam)
    print(px_var_name)
    print(xPx_title)

proc_single_file('0000.sdf')
```

It gives the following error:

```
starting file processing:0000.sdf
Particles_Px_subset_fract_electron
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phase_space_2d.py", line 227, in <module>
    proc_single_file(listfiles[i])
  File "phase_space_2d.py", line 156, in proc_single_file
    print(xPx_title)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'xPx_title' referenced before assignment
Object deleted
```

How I managed to solve it:

```
px_var_name = "Particles_Px_subset_fract_electron"
xPx_title = "Px vs. x"

def proc_single_file(file_nam):
    global xPx_title
    print("starting file processing:" + file_nam)
    print(px_var_name)
    print(xPx_title)

proc_single_file('0000.sdf')
```

```
starting file processing:0000.sdf
Particles_Px_subset_fract_electron
Px vs. x
```

Why is it that one of the variables get recognized while the other has to be declared as global inside the function?

Comment: Hmm. Can you check that you get the error on that first block of code.  I do not get it with 3.10

Comment: This code does not reproduce the error. Your real code assigns to `xPx_title` somewhere inside the function. Even if the assignment occurs *after* your attempt to print the value, that's still sufficient to make` xPx_title` a local variable that shadows the global with the same name in the *entire* function.

Comment: Adding `global xPx_title` ensures that assignments operate on the global without creating a new local variable.

Comment: even I could not replicate the error on other versions of Python. The code works just fine on my PC. Though the original code running on the remote location still shows the same error. For now, I have just explicitly mentioned the global nature of the variables inside the function. Though it works, I would like to understand why the error occurred in the first place.